# Webpack LESS-loader Unexpected character error

Tags: webpack, less, less-loader

i can't compile less files. I don't know where i'm doing mistake. 
Can u help me?

Error is: 
Failed to compile.

**./src/less/main.less 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

> @fontSize: font-size:20px;
>   | 
>   | p {**

here is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js', 
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'), 
        filename: 'main.js', 
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    }, 
    devServer: {
        overlay:true
    }, 
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.less$/, 
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader!less-loader"
                })
            }
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

and here is my **index.js**

import '../less/main.less';

and here is my **less** file

```
@fontSize: font-size:20px;

p {
    font-size: @fontSize;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@fontSize: 20px;`?

Comment: Ujin no there is @fontSize is variable, so it's should be @ fontSize: font-size:20px; i think loader is not working somewhere

Comment: have u review samples here : https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader

Comment: Hello i already looking there. what is difference ? my config same as how at this link. I already trying this too but not worked rules: [{
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
    }]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@fontSize: font-size:20px;` with `@fontSize: 20px;` and `use: "css-loader!less-loader"` with `use: ['css-loader', 'less-loader']`

Comment: not worked. giving error :     Error: Cannot find module 'less'

Comment: Do you have `less` and `less-loader` installed?

Comment: i have less-loader installed